# Error while making POST request to change user password

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, redux

when i try changing password using postman everything works but when i try to do that on the frontend i don't get any errors on the backend, the password isn't changed and i get error on network tab 'id is not valid'.

here is my backend:

routes:

```js
router.post("/reset", reset);
router.post("/reset/:userId/:token", changepw);
```

controllers:

```js
export const reset = async (req, res) => {
  const { email } = req.body;
  try {
    if (validateEmail(email) === false)
      return res.status(400).json({ error: "Please enter a valid email" });

    const user = await User.findOne({ email });
    if (!user) return res.status(404).json({ error: "User doesn't exist" });

    let token = await Token.findOne({ userId: user._id });
    if (!token) {
      token = await new Token({
        userId: user._id,
        token: crypto.randomBytes(32).toString("hex"),
      }).save();
    }

    const link = `http://localhost:3000/auth/reset/${user._id}/${token.token}`; 
                 // when the port is 5000 here its works on postman but when i set 3000 it doesn't work
    const result = await sendEmail(user.email, link);

    res.status(200).json({ result, token });
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({ error: "Something went wrong" });
    console.log(error);
  }
};

export const changepw = async (req, res, next) => {
  const { password, confirmPassword } = req.body;
  const { userId: _id, token } = req.params;

  try {
    if (!mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid(_id))
      return res.status(400).json({ error: "Id is not valid" });

    const user = await User.findById(_id);
    if (!user)
      return res.status(400).json({ error: "Invalid link or expired" });

    const tokens = await Token.findOne({
      userId: user._id,
      token,
    });
    if (!tokens)
      return res.status(400).json({ error: "Invalid link or expired" });

    if (password !== confirmPassword)
      return res.status(400).json({ error: "Passwords don't match" });

    const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, 12);
    const result = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(
      _id,
      { password: hashedPassword },
      { new: true }
    );
    await tokens.delete();

    res.status(200).json({ result, tokens });
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({ error: "Something went wrong" });
    console.log(error);
    next(error);
  }
};
```

here is the frontend:

this is how i connect backend and frontend:

```js
export const reset = (email) => API.post("/auth/reset", email);
export const changepw = (pw) => API.post("/auth/reset/:userId/:token", pw);
```

```js
<Route path="/auth/reset/:userId/:token" component={ChangePassword} />
// this the component where user go to change password
```

redux actions:

```js
export const reset = (email) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    const { data } = await api.reset(email);
    dispatch({ type: actionTypes.RESET, data });
  } catch (error) {
    const err = JSON.stringify(error?.response?.data);
    sessionStorage.setItem("error", err);
  }
};

export const changepw = (pw) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    const { data } = await api.changepw(pw);
    dispatch({ type: actionTypes.CHANGEPW, data });
  } catch (error) {
    const err = JSON.stringify(error?.response?.data);
    sessionStorage.setItem("error", err);
  }
};
```

reducers:

```js
export default (state = { user: null, link: null }, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
   case actionTypes.RESET:
      return { ...state, link: action.payload };
    case actionTypes.CHANGEPW:
      return { ...state, user: [state.user, action.payload] };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

this is what i do when user submit new password:

```js
const [data, setData] = useState({
    password: "",
    confirmPassword: "",
  });

const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    dispatch(changepw({ ...data }));
    setData({
      password: "",
      confirmPassword: "",
    });
    // history.push("/auth");
  };
```

Comment: In react router you have registered path="/auth/reset/:userId/:token" so that's what is called when you call changepw, not the backend. You need a different path/route for your back-end (i.e. /api/auth/...). It works in postman cause it doesn't know about the react route.

Comment: @Sirode I did that and i still get error on the network tab 'Id not valid'

Comment: Is your back-end running on different hostname and/or port? You should use the full URL http://back-end:port/xxx

Comment: Please use the full Url of your backend

Comment: ok thank you guys, the problem was in how I connected frontend and backend. i just changed: this export const changepw = (pw) =>
  API.post(`/auth/reset/:userId/:token`, pw);  to this export const changepw = (userId, token, pw) =>
  API.post(`/auth/reset/${userId}/${token}`, pw); and now its works